# Problem passing PHP variable to an AJAX file using json_encode

Tags: php, json, ajax

Working on a form which has got 3 phases. In phase 1 the user fills a form which is submitted to the backend for validation, some data computation and later passed to the 2nd phase where the user triggers a button which has a dynamic id. Next, I use AJAX to fetch the values the user entered in the 1st phase of the form to a final controller.

I store all the values the user entered in a PHP variable called oldata but when I try **json_encode()** the variable inside the AJAX code and log the values in console tab I dont get the data from the form.

**Phase 1**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2c.getplans') }}" class="form-contact"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('FirstName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="{{ old('FirstName') }}" required>
          <label>First Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
           @if ($errors->has('FirstName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('FirstName') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('MiddleName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName"  value="{{ old('MiddleName') }}" required>
          <label>Middle Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
          @if ($errors->has('MiddleName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('MiddleName') }}</strong>
                </span>
          @endif
        </div>

    <div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <input type="text-area" id="email" class="form-input" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
      <label>Email *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
       @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="phone" id="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
      <label>Phone Number *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('phone'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="date" class="form-input" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required>
      <label>Date of Birth *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="form-b3c" style="cursor:pointer;"> Get Plans</button>

  </form>
```

**Controller to handle phase 1**

```
 //Post Request of plan entries
    public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {   
        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'FirstName' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'MiddleName' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:20',
            'dob' => 'required|valid_birth_date',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        ]
        );

        //fetches all the unput values from the form
        $oldata = $request->all();


        $plans_benefits = view("B2C::travel.plans", compact(oldata))->render();
        return $plans_benefits;
    }
```

**Phase 2**

```
@if (!empty($plans_benefits))
    <div class="container">
        <div class="PLAN">
            <main class="top">
                <div class="row">
              @foreach ($plans_benefits as $plan_benefits)
                @php
                  $plan_data = $plan_benefits[0];
                  $benefits = $plan_benefits[1];
                  $plan_name = $plan_data->Calculation_TravelPlan->TravelPlan->Name;
                @endphp   
                  <div class="card plan">
                        <h5 class="card-title plan"> {{$plan_name}} </h5>
                            <img class="card-img-top plan" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/superior.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="travel-plan">
                  <div class="superior-content">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            @foreach($benefits as $benefit)
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="plan-title">{{$benefit->name}}</td>
                                    @if($benefit->value == 'true')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                                    @elseif ($benefit->value == 'false')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas"></i></td>
                                    @else
                                        <td class="plan-worth"> {{$benefit->value}} </td>
                                    @endif
                                </tr>
                             @endforeach
                           </tbody>
                        </table> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- Hiden-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"" class ="calc_id" name="calc_id" id="calc_id{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>

                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_name}}" class ="travelplan" name="travelplan" id="plan{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>
                    <!--Hidden-->

                      <p class="card-text plan">TOTAL
                        <span class="amount">$  {{round($plan_data->TravelBasicPremium,2)}} 
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <!-- AJAX call when the button is hit-->
                       <a id ="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}" class="plan-quote get_quote" style="cursor:pointer;"><span>Get Quote</span></a>
                    </div>
                     </div>
    @endforeach
      </div>
            </main>
        </div>
  </div>
@endif
```

**AJAX code**

```
 $('.PLAN').on('click', '.get_quote', function () {
                var olddata =  {!! json_encode($oldata) !!};
                console.log(oldata);

                var entries = oldata.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    //URL from routes file in Laravel
                    url: 'getquote',
                    //GET request
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: entries + '&calc_id=' + c_id + '&travelplan=' + plan_name,
                    success: function success(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function error(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                //END AJAX REQUEST
```

Comment: Typo? `var olddata` vs `console.log(oldata);`

Comment: I don't see the `get_quote` thing you want to click.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please check the post, I have added phase 2 of the form where I click a link with get_quote class.

Comment: @kerbholz Rectified the typo,,, still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Set dataType in your ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getquote',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "json"
    ...
 )};
```

Hope it will help.